# Check if an array contains 2 or more elements of another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I found a similar answer to my question here: Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript, unfortunately, the OP is asking if ANY elements equal to ANY elements in another array.

In my case, I actually need to check if `two or more elements equal to 2 or more elements in another array`. Otherwise, it should return false.

I tried methods similar to the mentioned question but I can't get it to target X number of matches...

```
Array.filter(el => el.colors.some(x => colors2.includes(x)))
```

This is good only for ANY number of matches...

Comment: Just check the `.length` of that result and you'd get the number of matches.

Comment: show array and expected result

Comment: can yuo show some code? @VLAZ

Comment: @Aviale your code: `Array.filter(el => el.colors.some(x => colors2.includes(x)))` my code: `Array.filter(el => el.colors.some(x => colors2.includes(x))).length`

Comment: helpful but didn't work. another filter method must be used instead of the some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use `array#filter` combined with `array#includes` to find all items in arr1 in arr2.

Then check the length of result.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [2, 3];

let result = arr1.filter(v1 => arr2.includes(v1));
console.log(result.length >= 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something working like this below if this is any useful.
Took example form  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and modified a little bit.

I would go with the @Nguyễn Văn Phong answer. Also, I would use underscore library or similar if you wanted to keep your code tidy. It is just my personal preference :)

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 
'present'];

 const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6 );

 const result1 = result.includes('exuberant');

 console.log(result);
 // expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]

 console.log(result1);
 // expected output: true
```